# Visual Basic (vba) no reconoce tildes o acentos

Tags: vba, tildes

tengo un problema con vba ya que no reconoce las tildes, cuando coloco una tilde en el nombre de algún módulo o la dirección de algún archivo la quita o me coloca la letra "Y", en la siguiente imagen escribí "PRODUCCIÓN" y me arrojó "PRODUCCIYN". Como puedo corregir la configuración para que me reconozca las tildes?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Pon un breve ejemplo de lo que intentas hacer. Por ejemplo, si creas una carpeta con acentos pega el código para qué veamos cómo lo haces. Pon también en qué sistema trabajas (Windows/Mac) y su versión.